# Help me understand the following probability concept.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ denote the number of red and white balls, respectively, obtained in drawing two balls from a bag containing two red, two white, and two black balls. The joint frequency is given by $f(X,Y)=\dfrac{\dbinom{2}{x} \dbinom{2}{y} \dbinom{2}{2-x-y}}{\dbinom{6}{2}}$.

My question: Where is $\dbinom{2}{2-x-y}$ coming from? What does it represent? If possible, can someone explain the numerator came out to be? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to choose $2$ balls in total, and $2-x-y$ is the number of black balls you must choose if you are choosing $x$ red balls and $y$ white balls.

If ${2 \choose x}$ is the number of ways of choosing $x$ red balls from $2$,

and ${2 \choose y}$ is the number of ways of choosing $y$ white balls from $2$,

then ${2 \choose 2-x-y}$ is the number of ways of choosing $2-x-y$ black balls from $2$.

These need to be multiplied so that when you add up $f(2,0)+f(1,1)+f(1,0)+f(0,2)+f(0,1)+f(0,0)$ you get a total probability of  $1$.